# Is creating a DataFrame from an Arrow Map Type supported?

Tags: python-polars

I am trying to create a DataFrame from an Arrow array which contains a simple map using pyarrow-8.0.0 and polars-0.13.50. I'm running into an error, and I was wondering if there is support for this:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import polars as pl
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = pa.map_("string", "string")
    arr = pa.array([[("one", "uno"), ("two", "dos")]], type=t)
    tbl = pa.table([arr], names=["trans"])
    df = pl.DataFrame(tbl)
    print(df.head())
```

Getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pdutta/vscode/sparkless/experiments/maptype.py", line 9, in <module>
    df = pl.DataFrame(tbl)
  File "/home/pdutta/.pyenv/versions/sparkless/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/internals/frame.py", line 308, in __init__
    self._df = arrow_to_pydf(data, columns=columns)
  File "/home/pdutta/.pyenv/versions/sparkless/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/internals/construction.py", line 615, in arrow_to_pydf
    pydf = PyDataFrame.from_arrow_record_batches(tbl.to_batches())
ValueError: Cannot create polars series from Map(Field { name: "entries", data_type: Struct([Field { name: "key", data_type: Utf8, is_nullable: false, metadata: {} }, Field { name: "value", data_type: Utf8, is_nullable: true, metadata: {} }]), is_nullable: false, metadata: {} }, false) type
```

Is this supported?